# PHP OOP no object returned

Tags: php, object, singleton

I am having trouble with getting the object returned in php. It only happens with my database object and all the others work fine, here's the code:

```
class D {
private static $instance;
private $connected=false,$db,$mf;

public static function getInstance() {
    if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
        self::$instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}


public function connect() {
    $mf = MF::getInstance();
    $this->r = R::getInstance();
    if($this->connected == false) {
        $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->r->mysql_host.';dbname='.$this->r->mysql_database, $this->r->mysql_username, $this->r->mysql_password);
        if($this->db == true) {
            $this->connected = true;
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
        }else{
            $this->mf->report('Unable to connect to database',2);
        }
    }else{
        $this->mf->report('Connection already made.');
    }
}

public function query($sql) {
    try {
        $q = $this->db->query($sql);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) { 
        trigger_error('<br>Regel: '.$e->getLine().'<br>
            Bestand: '.$e->getFile().'<br>
            Foutmelding: '.$e->getMessage().'<br>SQL: '.$sql,E_USER_ERROR); 
        die();
    } 
    return $q;
}
}
```

Now, when I use D::getInstance(); it doesn't return the object as it should do. It just gives me the 'Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object' error as soon as I execute the query() function. It only happens with the db, other objects like R and MF work fine when using getInstance(); and they all use the same code.

(And yes I first do $d = D::getInstance(); and then $d->connect(); before I load it in another object)

Comment: `var_dump( D::getInstance())` should return `object(D)` and not `Call to a member function query() ` can you show are you are calling it ???

Comment: If you define your class as a singleton, you should call `D::getInstance()`, not `new D`.

Comment: .. and call `connect` from your constructor

Comment: @Baba var_dump() returns 'object(D)#6 (3) { ["connected":"D":private]=> bool(false) ["db":"D":private]=> NULL ["mf":"D":private]=> NULL } ' and I meant that moonwave99, sorry about that (edited it in my post now)

Comment: Already did that @Karoly, somehow my getInstance() thinks I didn't however seen my var_dump

Comment: Singletons are evil by the way. Don't use them please. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40373/so-singletons-are-bad-then-what

Comment: Then what do you mean by `when I use D::getInstance(); it doesn't return the object as it should do`

Comment: You need to edit with your client code otherwise we are guessing. I presume it's the order of the method calls.

Comment: in your last line of the post, you mean `$d = D::getInstance();` instead of `$d::getInstance();`, right ?

Comment: @Seph after `$this->db = new PDO(...`, try `var_dump($this->db);`. see if the `$this->db` object is initialized properly.